Nonhomogenous Geometric Distribution Approach
I am trying to solve this problem by considering a geometric distribution with unequal probabilities.
First, I am using the Irwin-Hall Distribution to deduce that for n independent uniform random variables, $P(U_{1}+U_{2} + \dotsm + U_{n} \geq 1) = 1 - \frac{1}{n!}$
Thus, if we let $X$ = # of trials until success, then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(X=2) &= P(U_{1} + U_{2} \geq 1) \\
& = 1-\frac{1}{2} \\
& = \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(X=3) &= (1-P(X=2))P(U_{1} + U_{2} + U_{3} \geq 1) \\
& = (1-\frac{1}{2}) (1-\frac{1}{6}) \\
& = \frac{5}{12}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and in general if $n > 2$, it seems that $P(X = n) = (1-\frac{1}{n!})\displaystyle \prod_{k=2}^{n-1} (1-P(X=k))$
I am reading that the answer to this problem is supposed to be $e$. But using this approach I am getting $\approx 2.6$ for the expected value. Is something wrong in this approach?

Welcome to crossvalidated, Hamzah10!
This is your first question here :-) Reading the title, I had no clue what the question was about - you might want to consider changing the title to include what you are trying to solve, like ... approach to finding the mean number of uniform random variables such that the sum exceeds 1.

Your analysis has lost the relationship between the $X_k$ and the $U_k,$ which are not independent.
